# KDW60X16 Dishwasher - Not Pumping Water (Wash Pump)

Tags: dishwasher, electric-motor

I have the KDW60X16 dishwasher, and two days ago it started making a whirring noise.
It will fill and drain fine - But will not spray/move water at all. The motor makes a 'humming/buzzing' noise when it starts, and continues for some time until I stop it.

I have removed the motor (YXW50-2E) and checked for any blocks etc.

I have found that the impeller is broken. I assume that this is no good and *may* be causing my problem?

I have also checked the resistance on the motor and the manual states it should be:

116.2 Ohms (Main Coil)
101.5 Ohms (Assistant)
41.4 Ohms (M1)

All +/- 7%.

I have the following readings:

158.4 Ohms (Main Coil)
117.2 Ohms (Assistant)
41.9 Ohms (M1)

Does the above readings point to a faulty motor?

I also have access to a capacitance meter, so I have taken the starter capacitor off and it checks out at 2.9uf (Rated at 3uf) - I was really hoping this was the issue as its best described from the manual as this but appears not?

Any help you can give me would be invaluable :)

Images attached of the user manual plus the broken impeller.

[image: Impeller]

[image: Motor Ohms Spec]

Comment: Why not replace the broken impeller and then test again.

Answer (score 1):

You show a picture of yourself holding the smoking gun (if smoking guns can be wet): the wash pump impeller. Replace it, and you should be fine.